# What's the best way to try newer versions?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, updates, btrfs

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in two computers. One is the desktop version, my alternate (and almost) everyday computer, and a second server (headless) version.Eventually the server will be a file/media server for my home, but at the moment I am keen to use it to experiment, test out, and push the boundaries of both the server and the file system (I'd like to go with `btrfs` RAID5)

I have been testing `btrfs` on the server setup over the last few days but have just realised I'm running a slightly older version (3.12) than the current version (4.0-4.4). It is the current repository version. Also the kernel is 3.19 vs 4.4.

I would generally go for the "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" approach, however `btrfs` at this earlier version misses out on all the advancements made since then and towards 4.

Since I am purely testing for the time being (but later heading to production on this box in the coming month or two) how should I approach trying later versions of both the kernel and file system?

I do not have much experience with compiling and building modules myself, although I'm willing to learn, and I don't want to rely on the GUI since the server will be headless and worked on via SSH most of the time. I'm relatively comfortable on the command line.

#### What approach have you taken when it comes to "trying" later versions?

- Could I utilise proposed builds via `apt-get install`,
- Should I be downloading and building the kernel and btrfs myself, or
- Should I upgrade(?) to 15.10 and work from there?

Answer (score 0):

In April this year, the next LTS version (16.04) will be issued.  You will be able to upgrade to it directly from 14.04 LTS. It will contain up to date versions of btrfs and the kernel.

Upgrading to 15.10 (non-LTS) will require you to work through the intermediate upgrades (> 14.10 > 15.04 > 15.10).

Are you able to wait 2-3 months?

Comment: it is something I considered, but not really. I'd be hoping by then I'd be onto my next project and this one was put to bed. When I typed up the question, I looked at the release dates for U16 and even considered opting in for the alpha release (since this is only an experimental server at any rate), but I'd talked myself out of that. But in making this comment, I'm thinking myself INTO it :). I'm really not sure of the pros/cons of opting in so early